# Error: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, stream, webrequest, streamreader

I am getting the following exception in c#: Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

When calling ReadToEnd() method from a streamreader in a web application.

If i copy and paste the same code in a console application. It works.

Any ideas

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an exception, merely a warning from the debugger that it has trouble giving you the information you asked for.  That happens.  Do make sure you have set the breakpoint correctly and haven't ended up in non-managed code with Debug + Break All.

Comment: Ok i will check on that. What happen if it does fall in unmanage or native code ? And how to ignore this exception and continu the execution. The code stop executing after this message

Comment: Well ok this mean that this message won't appear when i will publish in release mode, since there debugger won't be present. By the way, sometimes it execute the method successfully, sometimes it won't.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are executing this code in a web method (service) like
PageMethod.

when the stream finish reading, it send the buffer to the client .. but there is no client to send the buffer to .. then this exception happen.

it happens in my code when i trying to download file using web method.